# Run Node.js application while booting in Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, node.js

I have to run a Node.js application while reboot in Raspberry Pi.The application uses WiFi and BLE on-board of Raspberry Pi.

I have tried out the below solutions:

1.Copied my Node.js application in the `rc.local` with full path.

```
cd path filename.js < /dev/null &
```

But it still didn't work.
Ref link :([How to run a script (Node.js) at startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/how-to-run-a-script-node-js-at-startup))

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well. What I finally had to do was create a script that starts the node.js application, and call that from rc.local.

myscript.sh

    `#!/bin/bash
    cd application path
    node application.js`

Then in rc.local, call myscript.sh with the full path.

Comment: how do you exactly 'call myscrip.sh' in the rc.local file? What do you type?